# Find possible sums that create N

Tags: integers

I want to create a function that creates an array with every permutation of the sum of positive integers that create a given integer (`N`).

The example `N = 3` would create an array of:

`1 + 1 + 1`
`2 + 1`

As I am not a mathematician I do not know the correct terminology so even answers about that would be helpful.

Comment: The correct terminology is *partition* of an integer.

Comment: Many thanks @ArnaudMortier , that has got me on the right lines.

Comment: You're very welcome!